# How do I match speed at which a rigid body and a smoke object are moved by wind force?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rigid-body-simulation, smoke-simulation, force-fields

How do I create a rigid body object (e.g., a sphere) and a smoke object that are both moved by wind at the same speed? My goal is that the rigid body object moves at the same pace as the leading edge of the smoke (ie the tip of the smoke). Is it maybe possible to attach the rigid body to the Smoke Adaptive Domain? The smoke is rendered in cycles and I am not using a particle system.

The smoke is not emitted by the moving object. The smoke is emitted from a source independent of the rigid body. The rigid body sphere should just move at the same speed as the smoke, so that it appears to reach a point at the same time.

I don't want to match these manually and don't want to build a path animation for the rigid body. Thanks!

I've tried playing around with the Mass physics property of the rigid body (see screenshot) but if it falls below 0.1 the sphere just jumps around really fast.

Here's screenshot of a quick illustration of the problem. The smoke and the rigid body are only moved by the force field (no gravity in this scene).

[image: illustration of problem; goal is to move the leading edge/tip of the smoke at the same speed as the rigid body sphere]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; why not make the rigid body object the smoke emitter?

Comment: thanks @gandalf3! The smoke is not emitted by the moving object. The smoke is emitted from a source independent of the rigid body. The rigid body sphere should just move at the same speed as the smoke, so that it appears to reach a point at the same time. I've updated the question accordingly and added a screenshot to clarify.